# Item in Active Record not rendering correctly - Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Not quite sure if 'Active Record' is the right term. The DB? Postgres?

I'm following through [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app#code-toy_user_presence_valications) and having a very frustrating issue. I've found quite a few posts on SO with people struggling, but majority of them went way off base for the answers, so I'm trying to find out what's wrong with my example.

**My User Controller**

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

```
  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
    end
end
```

**My User Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :micropost
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true

end
```

**My Microposts Model**

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :content, length: { maximum: 140 },
                      presence: true
end
```

**My Microposts Controller**

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_micropost, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /microposts
  # GET /microposts.json
  def index
    @microposts = Micropost.all
  end

  # GET /microposts/1
  # GET /microposts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /microposts/new
  def new
    @micropost = Micropost.new
  end

  # GET /microposts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /microposts
  # POST /microposts.json
  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.new(micropost_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @micropost.save
        format.html { redirect_to @micropost, notice: 'Micropost was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @micropost }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @micropost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /microposts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /microposts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @micropost.update(micropost_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @micropost, notice: 'Micropost was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @micropost }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @micropost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /microposts/1
  # DELETE /microposts/1.json
  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to microposts_url, notice: 'Micropost was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_micropost
      @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :user_id)
    end
end
```

**My show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @user.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Email:</strong>
  <%= @user.email %>
  <% if @user.micropost.any? %>
  <%= @user.micropost.first %>
  <% end %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

When I load a Users page (6 or 7 in my case) I am seeing 'something' being outputted in this format, but it's showing

Which I feel like is an Active Record (?) index? I'm not sure how to get it to show the first (or any) Micropost of a User.

In some solutions I saw people used render @user.micropost but I get an issue about partials (Which I'm familiar with) but the tutorial says you should be able to use the syntax used previously (aka @user.email ) to solve it. So I feel I'm over complicating it?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I needed to use

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @user.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Email:</strong>
  <%= @user.email %>
  <% if @user.micropost.any? %>
  <%= @user.micropost.first.content %>
  <% end %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) 

%> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

I should have realized when it was reporting a hash value.

Answer (score 0):

you can't be rendering the show page because if you did you would get a no method or for nil class.

Your show action has no instance variable called @user.

For your show to display data you need a user object.  In your case you have none.

So in your show method, add this:

@user.find_by(params[:id])

That will find the user 6 or 7 and allow you to call @

Can you paste the url from the browser so I can see where you actually are?